# vscode does not work when it has multiple cargo projects？

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

I'm learning to use rust，i am using vscode。
I have two cargo projects in my workspace，Why rust-analyzer only has an error message in the first project, but not in the second。
[image]

[image]

Is there any setting required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create workspace:

- Create `Cargo.toml` in your root project
- Add this code:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "./<your-cargo-project1>",
    "./<your-cargo-project2>",


]
```